# Error when starting Edge browser with script debugging enabled: "Received breakpoint event referencing unknown breakpoint"

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, asp.net-core, microsoft-edge

Recently, Edge script debugging support has been added to Visual Studio, which allows you to start Edge with the VS debugger attached. So I did exactly that and started my solution with script debugging enabled:

[image: Script Debugging Menu]

Alas, when I start the solution I get this error and the debugging process is stopped:

> Received breakpoint event referencing unknown breakpoint '1012'!
>
> [image: Error Message]

Hence, I can only start the solution with script debugging disabled.

You might find the following information useful:

- I am using MS Edge version 42.17134.1.0
- I am using Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7.2
- The project is ASP.NET MVC in .NET Core 2.1
- Script code is in TypeScript 2.8
- Server code is in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out what the problem was: There were some breakpoints scattered in the script code in Visual Studio (since before the development server was added to Edge). When I removed all of those breakpoints and added them again *while Edge was running*.

I would consider this a bug in either Edge or Visual Studio.

Comment: Problem can also occur when breakpoints were added while Edge was running and sometimes problem does not occur when breakpoints added before debugging was started; but in all cases, cleaning the breakpoints helps.

Answer (score 0):

Problem still present in VS 2017 15.7.2. Adding a breakpoint in Typescript during run causes Edge to stop immediately. Also IIS Express stops.
Breakpoints in async methods are not hit at all, even when added before.
Clearing all breakpoints before helps to start the browser.